# asp.net mvc after logout when login from other user previous users detail is showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I have a web application, when the first user logs in and open his profile and logout. 
 when second user login on same computer after logout first user, and open profile, it showing first user profile. second user has to refresh page. 
how to prevent this, I have used

```
 [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*")]
 public ActionResult profile()
 {
    usertb user = db.usertbs.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EMail == userid);
    return View(user );
 }
```

please help me solve it

Comment: How are you logging out the user. Please post your code.

Comment: as @lopezbertoni pointed out, best to show your logout method

Answer (score 4):

Does it work if you remove the `OutputCache` attribute from the action method?

```
//[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult profile()
{
   usertb user = db.usertbs.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EMail == userid);
   return View(user );
}
```

If so, you should be able to resolve this with 2 steps. First, put this in your Global.asax file:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    return "User".Equals(custom, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        ? User.Identity.Name
        : base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

After that, you can use the following `OutputCache` attribute on your action:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 60, VaryByCustom = "User")]
public ActionResult profile()
{
   usertb user = db.usertbs.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EMail == userid);
   return View(user );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is set the location of your OutputCache to Client, this will cache the personalize data on the browser and every user will gets a cache of his own.

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*", Location=OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
public ActionResult profile()
{
    usertb user = db.usertbs.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EMail == userid);
    return View(user );
}
```

See this:
[Improving Performance with Output Caching (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx)